# Perl-reordering rows in a tsv file

Tags: perl, sorting, csv

I'm hoping someone here can help me with an approach to solving the following problem. I have a tsv file with 300000 + rows of data which I wish to reorder. Short extract below:

```
src    dest    relationship
CK200    CK201    CK200-CK201
KY305    KY306    KY305-KY306
LM102    LM103    LM102-LM103
KY306    KY305    KY306-KY305
CK201    CK200    CK201-CK200
LM103    LM102    LM103-102
```

I would like to reorder the data in the following way.

```
src    dest    relationship
CK200    CK201    CK200-CK201
CK201    CK200    CK201-CK200
KY305    KY306    KY305-KY306
KY306    KY305    KY306-KY305
LM102    LM103    LM102-LM103
LM103    LM102    LM103-LM102
```

Would the best approach be to store this in a hash and use some kind of sort using the 'dest' value as a key?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! as I'm not sure of the best way of doing this from an efficiency point of view.

Thanks,
Shaw

Comment: You can expect down votes as you didn't put any effort to explain algorithm, nor did you show what did you try so far.

Comment: A hash is a good start, but you might hit memory problems. An showing what you've tried so far is also a good start, and gets much better answers.

Comment: Does this need to be in perl code? If not, you could just use `head`, `tail` and `sort` (if these programs are available).

Comment: It looks like you want to sort records using the first column, but what do you want to do in the case of a tie? Depending on the answer to that, you might be able to simply sort the lines in their entirety (no need for a hash).

Comment: Why did `CK200` go to `CK201`, while the `KY` and `LM` numbers stayed the same?

Answer (score 1):

```
# Original data
cat foo.tsv

src    dest    relationship
CK200    CK201    CK200-CK201
KY305    KY306    KY305-KY306
LM102    LM103    LM102-LM103
KY306    KY305    KY306-KY305
CK201    CK200    CK201-CK200
LM103    LM102    LM103-102

# Store the header info
head -n 1 foo.tsv > foo_sorted.tsv

# Sort the remainder, starting at line 2, and append to foo_sorted.tsv
tail -n +2 foo.tsv | sort >> foo_sorted.tsv

# Show the result
cat foo_sorted.tsv

src    dest    relationship
CK200    CK201    CK200-CK201
CK201    CK200    CK201-CK200  
KY305    KY306    KY305-KY306
KY306    KY305    KY306-KY305
LM102    LM103    LM102-LM103
LM103    LM102    LM103-102
```